# Toolbar title and options disappear on fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-toolbar

I have a MainActivity which is showing a fragment containing a TabLayout and ViewPager. If I comment out all the content in my onCreateView inside SearchFragment, my toolbar will appear as expected.

My problem is that the toolbar becomes blank when I use FragmentTransaction to show my fragment.

Pictures explaining my problem
[Fragment with blank toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PD96D.png)
[MainActivity with populated and titled toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlJak.png)

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);

    SearchFragment searchFragment = new SearchFragment();

    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    ft.add(searchFragment, null);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_create_item:
            //Button pushed in toolbar
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
}
```

SearchFragment.java

```
public class SearchFragment extends Fragment {
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    FragmentActivity v = getActivity();

    v.setContentView(R.layout.searchfragment);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 1"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 2"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 3"));
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter
            (v.getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}
}
```

searchfragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and lastly activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What is v.setContentView(R.layout.searchfragment); in fragment? You should do it by layout inflater.

Comment: I have found out I have to use setContentView with the fragments layout containing the TabLayout, or I will get nullpointer exception on tabLayout object. I check out what you mean by layout inflater cause I'm not sure exactly what you mean.

Answer (score 3):

I have found the issue to be that the toolbar is set at the top of onCreateView. I have to set the toolbar at the very bottom of OnCreateView on my SearchFragment, like so:

```
        FragmentActivity v = getActivity();

    v.setContentView(R.layout.searchfragment);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 1"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 2"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 3"));
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter
            (v.getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
    Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) v.findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    v.setTitle("Mit fragment");
```

So the toolbar has to be one of the last items to be done I guess.

Comment: A weird solution, but worked for me. Setting the toolbar text as the last statement in onCreate();

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

`setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE)` into `MainActivity.java`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ...

    Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
    }

    ...

}
```

---

and set title into `SearchFragment.java`'s `onCreateView` function

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ...

    getActivity().setTitle("My Fragment");

    ...

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it makes no changes. The actionbar is still blank. I'm now going to to try and make a super simple activity and fragment with just an actionbar - no viewpager or tablayout.